# externally work around randomised mac addresses

Tags: mac-address

we have a few devices here at our business that need to be connected to the network, however as an 'inbuilt' feature they randomise their mac address every time they turn on, both via the Ethernet and WiFi interface.

this plays havoc with the corporate networks since the network admins fix an IP to a mac address, one that clearly doesn't last very long.

what we're looking to do is come up with some sort of device to sit externally to these devices, and take the connection from the device and retransmit with a fixed mac address.

is that possible from a network engineering point of view?

Comment: What kind of devices are these?

Comment: 3D printers, it's difficult to connect to them to a corporate network where the MAC addresses are key.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is actually just NAT. You could put a small router in front of the devices. On one side of the router, the devices will be put into a dedicated subnet, getting their IPs dynamically from DHCP. Any traffic from the devices will be source-NATed by the router so that the rest of the network will see all traffic from the devices as coming from a single IP.

If you have a requirement to be able to distinguish each device individually, you could have one subnet per device, and then do a distinct source NAT for each of those subnets. So each device will have a predictable "visible IP", even if its local IP in the subnet is changing all the time.